# How can I design these shapes on a page using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a site from a PSD document but I have no idea how to create this shape in my nav.

Is it a big `<div>` with negative `margin-top` and some `border-radius`?

[image: https://gyazo.com/783397229341b950567379c7d046912e]

Also, how can this design be achieved on a page using bootstrap? Like the div is coming from outside the center area and the "chat bubble effect" from the client photo.

[image: https://gyazo.com/45f304577db867934afa652b847cb744]

Comment: Check out Border-radius , With that you can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

For first question

```
border-bottom-left-radius: value;

border-bottom-right-radius: value;
```

On the second question - the question is not quite clear.

Comment: How can I replicate the blue `div` with 'OUR CLIENTS SAY' and the Chat Bubble Effect that has the review written in it? Also how can I make the Blue div expand to the border of the page?

Comment: Make a blue block - many ways, one of them is to set the blue block position: absolute;
and the required width.
And for the block with the text position: relative; overflow: visible;

About Chat Bubble Effect.
There are a lot of ways that specifically causes difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

for the bottom radius you can try this code:

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties  `border-bottom-left-radius: value;` and `border-bottom-right-radius: value;` to create a rounded bottom in an element. Below is an example similar to the screenshot in your post

```css
.div-container {
  font-size:12px;
  width:220px;
  padding:5px 30px;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #222;
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
}
.div-right{
  padding:5px 30px 6px 30px;
  left:40px;
  display:inline;
  position:relative;
  background:#4286f4;
  color:white;

  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "div-container">
  916.543.1543
<div class = "div-right">
GET A FREE QUOTE
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And should I place it in the `nav` or make a separate `div` above the nav?

Comment: I think either would work, depending on the structure of your website.